# Cannot update list item properties Server Object Model in context of SP, can update via CSOM

Tags: document-library, client-object-model, splistitem

I am trying to update a SPListItem metadata properties after inserting this document into a document library.

Fortunately though the CSOM, this is quite easy:

```
private void UpdateListItemProperty(object value, PropertiesEnum prop, ListItemCollection listItems, ClientContext ctx)
        {
            foreach (ListItem li in listItems)
            {
                li[EnumHelper.GetDescription(prop)] = value;
                li.Update();
            }
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        }
```

Unfortunately, I also have to do it Server Object Model, in context of SharePoint, and it does not populate boolean/date fields. Stangely, not ALL text fields populate either, but definetly some do. How do I update properties this way?

```
private static void UpdateListItemProperties(SPListItem listItem)
        {
listItem.Properties["MyFirstTextField"] = "Blah"; //works fine
listItem.Properties["TextField_x0020_WithSpace"] = "string"; //doesn't work
listItem.Properties["MyFirstBoolField"] = true; //doesn't work
listItem.Update();
}
```

Wehn I say works/doesn't work; I mean the list item properties are not updated.

Ideally I don't have to rename the columns that i am already populating fine through CSOM, just to be able to populate them through SP.

Note: in CSOM it actually uses a `ListItem` and in SOM it uses `SPListItem`

Comment: did you tried removing _x0020_ ?

Answer (score 1):

First thing to try:

```
listItem["MyFirstTextField"] = "Blah"; //works fine
listItem["TextField_x0020_WithSpace"] = "string"; //doesn't work
listItem["MyFirstBoolField"] = true; //doesn't work
listItem.Update();
```

Remove the Properties part.. The above actually consider you provide the Internal name of the fields, the internal name is obviously different from the display name.. I hope you are already aware as you replace space with `_x0020_`

Comment: No I most certainly was not aware, as that is **exactly how IT IS** required when you use the CSOM

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that CSOM requires the 'encoded' names, i.e. `TextField_x0020_WithSpace`

If you use the server object model, in context of sharepoint, you can just specify it with the space:

`listItem["TextField WithSpace"] = "value";`

It's an awesome undocumented feature of sharepoint that wasted a cpl hours of my time.

Isn't it great how to do the exact same thing, you have to write two completely different sets of code!